# prevent storing a video file twice in internal storage in android

Tags: android

how to prevent storing same file selected in galary  twice  in internal storage in android .I tried with below code it copies same video many times in a folder in  the internal storage .

```
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {           
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                new SaveVideoInFolder().execute(uri);            
                try {
                    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    File storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
                    File app_directory = new File(storage, "video_choosing");                 
                    if (!app_directory.exists())
                        app_directory.mkdirs();
                    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());                 
                    String filename = String.format("VID_%s.mp4", timestamp);  
                     file = new File(app_directory, filename);                   
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,file.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);    
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int read;

                    while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                        output.write(buffer, 0, read);

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                  
                    Log.e("TAG", "File Not Found", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {                 
                    Log.e("TAG", "IOException", e);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(app_directory, filename);
if(file.exists()){
  ...
}

else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: My filename is unique , I am saving the video file name with the current time ,so evertime it differs

Answer (score 0):

// Create the storage directory if it does not exist

`if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
             /*   Log.e(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");*/
                return null;
            }`

only you have check that your file is exist bt if condition and make directory if it is not..